# Jar Mismatch while using ActionBarSherlock and FacebookSdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

I am working on a project which has ActionBarSherlock and FacebookSdk as dependencies. On adding the libraries to the project,there is a jar mismatch as both contain android-support-v4.jar.

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android] Versions found are:
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android] Path: /home/privly-android/dependencies/actionbarsherlock/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android]  Length: 648327
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android]  SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android] Path: /home/privly-android/dependencies/facebook/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android]  Length: 987314
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android]  SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
[2015-02-19 21:57:08 - privly-android] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Answer (score 0):

From your error log `All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.` its very clear that both needs to be same.

copy same `android-support-v4.jar` in both sdk and it would work.